# WindowsからAmazon RDS へのDB接続 SSHトンネル

Tags: windows, ssh, amazon-rds

WindowsでHeidi SQLクライアントツールからAmazon RDSのMySQLに接続したいのですがうまくいきません。以下のエラーがでます。

```
Connection failed SSH exited unexpedted Command line was plink.exe -ssh ユーザ名@エンドポンと　-P 22 -i "鍵の場所"　-N -L ・・・
```

plink というSSH接続ツールがうまく機能していないのでしょうか？

Windowsで手っ取り早くAmazon RDS にSSHトンネルで接続できるクライアントソフトがあれば教えてください。

参考にしたサイト
https://into-the-program.com/aws-rds-heidisql/

PowerShellで下記を実行

```
 "C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\plink.exe" ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
発生場所 行:1 文字:39
+ "C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\plink.exe" ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
式またはステートメントのトークン 'ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' を使用できません。
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

CMDで実行すると

```
"C:\Program Files\HeidiSQL\plink.exe" -ssh -i " C:\Downloads\importants\kagi.ppk"  ec2-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Unable to use key file " C:\Downloads\importants\kagi.ppk" (unable to open file)
Using username "ec2-user".
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

HeidiSQLから　ssh.exe?かつ.pem を選択した場合

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

powershell からは
下記コマンド　でEC2インスタンスにログイン可能です。

ssh ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  -i C:\Downloads\importants\kagi.pem

Answer (score 2):

RDS インスタンス自体は ssh 接続することができません。

参考にされているサイトでは、RDS インスタンス以外に Linux の EC2 インスタンスがあり、それを踏み台にすることが想定されています。plink ツール自体は EC2 インスタンスに接続する形になるため、plink に指定する IP アドレスは EC2 インスタンスに割り当てられているパブリック IP アドレスにします。そのような構成で試されているでしょうか？

他に考えられる方法としては、以下のような方法があります。

- RDS にパブリック IP アドレスを割り当てて SSH を使わずに接続する (セキュリティ上あまりおすすめの方法ではありませんが簡単です)
- Windows の EC2 インスタンスを立ち上げて、そこから RDP 接続する。

ドキュメントには以下のようにほぼ同じことが書かれています。
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html#CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.ScenariosForAccess